# SOCI data types in wxWidgets applications

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, soci

I have started a new simple wxWidgets application, and then added support to firebird database acces using SOCI.
I want to know if it is possible to use data types like `wxString` and `wxDateTime` bacause I have already designed my table structre with'em.

TIA.

Comment: there's a wxString constructor to convert from std::string `wxString mystring(stlstring);` and back with `wxString::ToStdString()` or you can build wxwidgets with STL support https://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/faq/general/#stl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely possible to do this, but you will have to write `soci::type_conversion<>` specializations for these types yourself. This is quite straightforward, at least if you assume that strings are always encoded using UTF-8 in the database.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about this `type_conversion` before.